# Display categories/tags related to a post format - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I have a Wordpress 4.0 site where the owner will be using Post Formats to organize their posts. All blog posts are Standard and all video posts are Video.

I would like to be able to display a list of all categories with the post format = Video.

I would also like a list of tags or a tag cloud with the same post format.

This way I can display them on the page that shows all of the videos. I don't want any categories or tags that are related to the Standard Post Format to show up unless the tag is used in both Video and Standard formats. The it should show up but when the link is clicked it should only return tags with the Video format.

I have searched for something like this and I can't find it and I don't even know if this is possible so if you have any idea in which direction to look I would appreciate your help.

I don't know but I may be able to incorporate some of the search function that I am trying to get to work here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793742/wordpress-4-0-search-by-post-format.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is quite an interesting one. `post_format` (remember, standard is not a post format) is a taxonomy, so are `category` and `post_tag`. So you are dealing here with three equaly ranked taxonomies. It also looks like tags and categories can be shared between video and standard posts. To achieve your goal, I would rather look into custom post types and custom taxonomies. To achieve what you want with the current structure, it is going to mean quite expensive queries

Comment: Just a note, if tags and categories are going to be shared, it really would not matter if you make use of custom post types and taxonomies or not. Both are going to mean quite expensive queries to separate categories and tags used by videoa and standard posts